# What is a quadratic error function?

Tags: functions, quadratics

I'm currently reading a paper about [dual contouring](http://www.frankpetterson.com/publications/dualcontour/dualcontour.pdf)
and I have no idea, what a quadratic error function is. Could someone explain that?

Comment: Quadratic error function: an error function that is quadratic.

Comment: Maybe the details in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734792/dual-contouring-and-quadratic-error-function) (and the posted answers) will help you?

Comment: Thank you Jose, the other post really helped me out!